# Are @{$list_ref} and @$list_ref equivalent in Perl?

Tags: perl, dereference

I am new to Perl and am curious whether `@{$list_ref}` and `@$list_ref` are perfectly equivalent.

They seem to be interchangeable, but I am nervous that there is something subtle going on that I may be missing.

Comment: Recommended reading: `perldoc perlreftut`. Breaks down almost everything you need to know about references into very simple pieces, so that you can learn them with confidence :)

Comment: @hobbs That's the second time I've seen perlreftut mentioned. I guess I had better read it. :-)

Comment: @hobbs +1; also perllol: http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html

Comment: All the perldoc tutorials (those listed in the "Tutorials" section when you type `perldoc perl`) are must-reads. They start off at the shallow end and get progressively more difficult, so they're really nice for learning the language in little steps without being overwhelming.

Comment: also see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they're equivalent. You need braces when the expression is more than a simple scalar variable, *e.g.*,

```
push @{ $foo{$bar} } => "baz";
```

For more detail, see the [Using References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) section of the [documentation on references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). The standard Perl documentation also includes several tutorials on using references:

- [Understand References Today](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) (mentioned by [hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) in the question's comments)
- [Manipulating Arrays of Arrays in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)
- [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 6):

I've always found it helpful to remember that the outer braces are not syntactical magic, they're just a block that returns a reference. The expression inside the block can be anything that returns a reference:

```
$ perl -le 'sub foo {[qw/ apple orange banana /]} print ${print "Do something here."; foo()} [1]'
Do something here.
orange
```